# Top Questions of the Week #21

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 21 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and its contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If a password is compromised, is a "similar" password also compromised?](https://superuser.com/questions/299424/if-a-password-is-compromised-is-a-similar-password-also-compromised) can be interesting...

Answer (score -2):

["why does the resource hacker editor show up instead of log on screen"](https://superuser.com/questions/301805/why-does-the-resource-hacker-editor-show-up-instead-of-log-on-screen)

If it is genuine, it has to be one of the most unusual I have ever seen.

Comment: It doesn't make an interesting question in a way that can be explored in more details and with explanations. It'd make good blog material if it happened to Mark Russinovich and he'd dissect it in-depth, but not for us.